# Solr. how configurate Distributing function across Shards.

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I use Solr 4.0. I use Solr cloud. There is hash function for distributing(like round-robin algorithm ) in SolrCloud.

Can I change this function by plugin? Is there this plugin in configurations ? 
If yes, How can I do it ?

TNX

Comment: there is a custom hashing pluggability implemented in solr 4.1. Take a look: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2592?attachmentSortBy=dateTime#attachmentmodule The documentation is pretty sparse, the code is your friend at this point.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a completely custom sharding functionality, you can do the following:
1. Don't define the numShards parameter in your JAVA_OPTS. This will set sharding into 'implicit' mode
2. Pass the *shard* parameter as a part of your update request.